# How to add underlines to a multiline input in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

so this displays an underline under a single TextField

```
TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Notes.....',
    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
    border: new UnderlineInputBorder(
       borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black87,
       width: 1.0, style: BorderStyle.solid)
```

But when I do this

```
TextField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
    minLines: 100,
    masLines: 500,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Notes.....',
    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
    border: new UnderlineInputBorder(
       borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black87,
       width: 1.0, style: BorderStyle.solid)
```

It disappears?  Is there anyway to have the lines show up?

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
     TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              minLines: 100,
              maxLines: 500,
              style: TextStyle(
                decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
              ),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: 'Notes.....',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
              ),
            ),
```

If you'd still like to change the *colour* or *type* or *density* of the underline use the `decorationStyle` ,`decorationColor` and `decorationThickness` properties.

:)

Comment: Unfortunately this only shows up under the hint.  I wanted all of the lines to be underlined before beginning to type.  Thanks for the help though.